# XSLT counting elements child nodes(multiple child nodes) have a specific value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to count number of count number of element where all the value element  are 0.
I am using XSLT1.0
I have used

```
count(//element[value ='0'])
```

but it gives count if one of the value is 0  (so the count comes to 3) not all the value are 0(count should be 1).

```
<root>
  <element>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>1</value>
  </element>
</root>
```

I can use

```
count(//element[value !='0'])
```

to count elements that are not zero but looking for a solution that can count 0.

Thanks.

Comment: So why not `count(//element[not(value != 0)])`?

Comment: I can use it , but it  adds extra layer.
I have a code that is already written 
if count = 1
do x
if count = 2
do y

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean by "extra layer". Does it count the nodes you want to be counted or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression. It subtracts the count of the `value`s which are `0` from the overall count of `value`s:

```
count(//element[count(value) - count(value[text()='0']) = 0])
```